# Can You List the Names of Some Algorithms For Determining the Intersection of Two Context Free Grammars?

Tags: algorithms, context-free, decision-problem, sets

Suppose we have two sets of strings XS and YS such that set XS is described by grammar GX and YS is described by grammar GY.

We want an algorithm which accepts GX and Gy as inputs. The algorithm will return `true` if the intersection of sets XS and YS is non-empty and will return `false` otherwise. We do not need to know exactly what the intersection is. It is possible that the intersection set is massive, so returning a container of all elements is unreasonable. Describing the intersection as a grammar is okay as long as it's apparent whether the grammar actually describes a non-empty set of string or not.

Just the name of the algorithm is fine if a Google search using that name will bring up the result. If the algorithm is obscure, additional information would be helpful.

Comment: It seems [you are not aware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8827807/idlecustard?tab=questions) that you can accept an answer if you are the asker. It is part of protocol and etiquette to try accepting the best answer that has answered your question by [clicking on the check mark beside the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks without upvote or acceptance might be the antithesis of appreciation. A low acceptance rate may drive some users away from answering. You can check [how important is accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163740).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such algorithm. Start by googling undecidability. The problem itself is called "[language intersection/disjointness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Language_disjointness)".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63896)

Comment: @xskxzr Thank you for your review. Yes it was meant as a comment, but ended up in the wrong box. I am happy you recognized the critique. I am confident that the added relevant information makes this an adequite answer.